# Vectorizing nested loops in matlab using bsxfun and with GPU

Tags: performance, matlab, gpu, vectorization, bsxfun

For loops seem to be extremely slow, so I was wondering if the nested loops in the code shown next could be vectorized using `bsxfun` and maybe GPU could be introduced too.

**Code**

```
%// Paramaters
i = 1;
j = 3;
n1 = 1500;
n2 = 1500;

%// Pre-allocate for output
LInc(n1+n2,n1+n2)=0;

%// Nested Loops - I 
for x = 1:n1
    for y = 1:n1
        num = ((n2 ^ 2) * (L1(i, i) + L2(j, j) + 1)) - (n2 * n * (L1(x,i) + L1(y,i)));
        LInc(x, y) = L1(x, y) + (num/denom);
        LInc(y, x) = LInc(x, y);
    end
end

%// Nested Loops - II
for x = 1:n1
    for y = 1:n2
        num = (n1 * n * L1(x,i)) + (n2 * n * L2(y,j)) - ((n1 * n2 * (L1(i, i) + L2(j, j) + 1)));
        LInc(x, n1+y) = num/denom;
        LInc(n1+y, x) = LInc(x, n1+y);
    end
end
```

**Edit 1:** `n` and `denom` could be assumed as constants too.

Comment: You have two difference indexes: `x,y` and `i,j`, but `i,j` are not defined here.  Please either include more code that describes `i,j` or rewrite the code so that it is can create reproducible results.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention i = 1 and j =3, an n1 and n2 are also defined constants....

Comment: You should preallocate `LInc`

Comment: What is `denom`?  I'm assuming it's another constant?

Comment: yeah, I have preallocated LInc of order n1+n2 and denom is another constant

Comment: @NishantSaurabh What have you pre-allocated them with? Zeros?

Comment: @Divakar : yeah, LInc as zero matrix on GPU

Comment: and I have already calculated L1 of order n1 and L2 of order n2

Comment: @Divakar : Thanks Divakar, I did it, I am a new user here so didnt know much about it......

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are vectorized `CPU` and `GPU` codes and I am hoping that I am using at least good practices for the `GPU` code and the benchmarking later on.

## CPU Code

```
%// Pre-allocate for output
LInc(n1+n2,n1+n2)=0;

%// Calculate num/denom value for stage 1 and 2
nd1 = L1 + (((n2 ^ 2) * (L1(i, i) + L2(j, j) + 1)) - n2*n*bsxfun(@plus,L1(:,i),L1(:,i).'))./denom; %//'
nd2 = (bsxfun(@plus,n1*n*L1(:,i),n2*n*L2(:,j).') - ((n1 * n2 * (L1(i, i) + L2(j, j) + 1))))./denom; %//'

%// Plug in the values in the output matrix
LInc(1:n1,1:n1) = tril(nd1) + tril(nd1,-1).'; %//'
LInc(n1+1:end,1:n1) = nd2.';  %//'
LInc(1:n1,n1+1:end) = nd2;
```

## GPU Code

```
%// Pre-allocate for output
gLInc = zeros(n1+n2,n1+n2,'gpuArray');

%// Convert to gpu arrays
gL1 = gpuArray(L1);
gL2 = gpuArray(L2);

%// Calculate num/denom value for stage 1 and 2
nd1 = gL1 + (((n2 ^ 2) * (gL1(i, i) + gL2(j, j) + 1)) - n2*n*bsxfun(@plus,gL1(:,i),gL1(:,i).'))./denom; %//'
nd2 = (bsxfun(@plus,n1*n*gL1(:,i),n2*n*gL2(:,j).') - ((n1 * n2 * (gL1(i, i) + gL2(j, j) + 1))))./denom; %//'

%// Plug in the values in the output matrix
gLInc(1:n1,1:n1) = tril(nd1) + tril(nd1,-1).'; %//'
gLInc(n1+1:end,1:n1) = nd2.';  %//'
gLInc(1:n1,n1+1:end) = nd2;

%// Gather data from GPU back to CPU
LInc = gather(gLInc);
```

## Benchmarking

GPU benchmarking tips were taken from [Measure and Improve GPU Performance.](http://www.mathworks.in/help/distcomp/measure-and-improve-gpu-performance.html)

```
%// Warm up GPU call with insignificant small scalar inputs, just in case
%// gputimeit doesn't do the same
temp1 = modp2(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1); %// This is vectorized GPU code

i = 1;
j = 3;
n = 1000; %// Assumed
denom = 1e6;  %// Assumed

N_arr = [50 100 200 500 1000 1500]; %// array elements for N (datasize)
timeall = zeros(3,numel(N_arr));

for k1 = 1:numel(N_arr)
    N = N_arr(k1);
    n1 = N;  %// n1, n2 are assumed identical for less-complicated benchmarking
    n2 = N;

    L1 = rand(n1,n1);
    L2 = rand(n2,j);

    f = @() modp0(i,j,n1,n2,L1,L2,n,denom);%// Original CPU w/ preallocation
    timeall(1,k1) = timeit(f);
    clear f

    f = @() modp1(i,j,n1,n2,L1,L2,n,denom);%// Vectorzied CPU code
    timeall(2,k1) = timeit(f);
    clear f

    f = @() modp2(i,j,n1,n2,L1,L2,n,denom);%// Vectorized GPU(GTX 750Ti) code
    timeall(3,k1) = gputimeit(f);
    clear f
end

%// Display benchmark results
figure,hold on, grid on
plot(N_arr,timeall(1,:),'-b.')
plot(N_arr,timeall(2,:),'-ro')
plot(N_arr,timeall(3,:),'-kx')
legend('Original CPU','Vectorized CPU','Vectorized GPU (GTX 750 Ti)')
xlabel('Datasize (N) ->'),ylabel('Time(sec) ->')
```

## Results

[image]

## Conclusions

Results show that the vectorized GPU code performs really well with higher datasize and goes from slower than both the vectorized CPU and original code to being twice as fast as the vectorized CPU code.

Comment: +1 for taking such a poorly formatted question and making something cool out of it. Awesome on the timing graphs!

Comment: @rayryeng I saw the potential in it and the name `bsxfun` was enough to drag me into it :) Appreciate the UP!!

Answer (score 0):

If you have not done so, you should preallocate LInc.

```
LInc = zeros(n1,n2);
```

If you want to vectorize it, you don't need to use bsxfun to vectorize your code. I think you can do something like

```
x = 1:n1;
y = 1:n1;
num = ((n2 ^ 2) * (L1(i, i) + L2(j, j) + 1)) - (n2 * n * (L1(x,i) + L1(y,i)));
                    LInc(x, y) = L1(x, y) + (num/denom);
```

However, this code is confusing to me because as it is, you are overwriting the value of LInc several times. Without knowing what your goal is its hard for me to help more. The above code probably will not return the same values as your function.

Comment: You probably need `meshgrid` or `ndgrid` or `repmat` to create 2D `num`.

Comment: good point, the L1(x,i) and the L1(y,i) probably need to be made 2D, and one of them transposed

Comment: Exactly! And basically the way the nested loops are set, lower triangular part would be superimposed into the upper triangular part.

Comment: Thanks guys, These comments helped alot to understand bsxfun works and @Diwakar : Your code helped me greatly to understand how bsxfun works,

Comment: Guys, Thanks alot, I implemented sameway as you people suggested,and my application is speeded up by almost 250 times.....

Comment: @NishantSaurabh Wow!!! That's crazy man! Congratulations! :) It's about time people look into `vectorization with GPUs`!